# Updating the field of a nested object property inside an array of objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created the following schema in MongoDB. It is a customer schema with a sub-schema for storing the transactions. Each transaction is an object and each object(a transaction) contains a field called "transactionDetails", which is an object as well.

```
const transactionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    transactionType: {
      type: String,
    },
    transactionDetails: {
      transferredFrom: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
      transferredTo: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
      balance:{
        type: Number,
        default:0,
     
        min: 0,

      },
    
      amount:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
      }
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const customerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide a customer name"],
    },
    dob: {
      type: Date,
      required: [true, "Please provide a Date of Birth"],
    },
    address: {
      type: String,
      default: "India",
    },
    accNo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide an email address"],
    },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide a phone number"],
    },

    transactions: [transactionSchema],
    currentBal: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "Please provide valid balance"],
      default: 0,
      min:0
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

All I want to do is to set the value of a field to an existing field in the document while updating it. I want to set the value of "balance" field to the current updated value of the "currentBal" after the "currentBal" field has been updated.

The problem is that the no matter what I did, the value of "balance" field always set to default value without throwing any error

```
  Customer.findOneAndUpdate(
    { accNo: id },
    {
      $inc: { currentBal: Number(amount),
      },

      $push: {
        transactions: {
          transactionType: "deposit",
          transactionDetails: {
            transferredFrom: "Self",
            transferredTo: "Self",
            balance:{currentBal} ,
            amount: Number(amount),
          },
         
        },
      },
    },
    (err, customer) => {
      if (err !== null && err.name === "ValidationError") {
        res.json({ message: err._message });
      } else {
        console.log("Balance has been updated successfully");
        // console.log(customer.currentBal);
        res.redirect(`/customers/${id}`);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Is `currentBal` defined in the scope?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? @ypahalajani

Comment: I mean, when you are setting `currentBal` to the `balance` key in the update query object, is it defined at that point? I am asking this because I don't see it being declared in the code that you've shared.